# Rails Return Error on Class Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, model

I have a class method that I would like to return a error from, is something like this possible?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.do_this
  if b = Bar.find_by_id(5)
   return 'Yea' 
  else
   self.errors.add_to_base('I was not found')
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: what do you think about return an error_form ? It's the model, not the view or controller.

Comment: I am not familiar with returning an "error_form".  Could you please elaborate/provide an example.  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible because `errors` is an instance method while in this case `self` is the Foo class.

If you run this code, you'll get an error as follows:

```
undefined method `errors' for #<Class:0xb5f376d0>
```